# Different headline view with Mac/PC of emacs/orgmode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use the same org mode (7.01h) for PC and Mac.
The thing is that for headline, the mac shows only the last * by changing all the pre *'s color to the same as the background, whereas the orgmode in PC shows all the *'s. 
I prefer Mac's way.

What makes this difference? How can I show only the last * in the headline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variable `org-hide-leading-stars`.

You can either `M-x customize-variable` `org-hide-leading-stars` or just `(setq 'org-hide-leading-stars)` in your .emacs file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes the difference between the two operating systems you use, but you can choose to hide the stars by adding

`#+STARTUP: hidestars`

to the top of your org file. For more information check the [manual page on in-buffer settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wonder if I can do the same thing by adding one line in .emacs file.